# Probability if variable has $15\%$ CV

Tags: probability, calculus-of-variations, estimation, variance

I have a relatively simple question, but I am not sure if I understand it right.

I have estimated through my calculations the value $X$. $X$ depends on many things, but one of them is $Y$ and I know that $Y$ has a coefficient of variation of $15\%$.

QUESTION: I need to estimate the value of $X$ that probability that $X$ should fall below that number is less than $10\%$.

Do I understand is correct: $Y$ varies by $\pm15\%$. And now then I calculate my $X$ value based on this, I have a probability of $100-15 = 85\%$ that my value of $Y$ would be $10\%$ lower due to that?

Comment: The coefficient of variation only tells you about uncertainty in $Y$.  Without knowing how $X$ depends on $Y$ that is not enough information.

Comment: During calculation X and Y are multiplied. But I do not know anything more... I just have a final value of X and I am asked to tell what is my estimation of X value that would be for sure no less than 10% if CV of Y is 15%.

Comment: Perhaps you have mis-stated the problem?  As it stands, you say that $X$ depends on $Y$ but you don't say how.  So maybe $X=1+10^{-100}Y$ in which case a small uncertainty in $Y$ is irrelevant.  Now you say you are really interested in $XY$ but what does that have to do with computing $X$?

Comment: Also you appear to use $X$ and $Y$ interchangeably...what, for example, does "$Y$ varies by $\pm15\%$. And now then I calculate my $X$ value based on this, I have a probability of $100-15 = 85\%$ that my value of $Y$ would be $10\%$ lower due to that?" mean?

Comment: I made it complicated… What I mean is that I need to estimate X for which the probability that it should fall below that number is less than 10%. And I need to base my calculation on the assumption that CV of Y is 15%.

Comment: Right.  But you can not do that without some knowledge of how $X$ depends on $Y$.

Comment: Well, I didnt get any more data so cannot tell anything more. What kind of information should I look for? How much the Y vary depending on X? Or something else?

Comment: Covariance of $X,Y$ is a good start.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will ask for more data.